# Retrieving data from Firebase database to webView in Android

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-realtime-database, android-webview

I am building an application with **webView** and **Firebase** as database, I have implemented both correctly but the problem is that my webView is **not retrieving** any data from Firebase database and is showing blank when I open application, I have checked the webView by adding **URL** directly and it shows web page but it does not show anything when I use it with Firebase, please help to sort this thing out.

> I am using Android Studio

**webView class file:**

```
public class webViewNews extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webviewthis;
    private RecyclerView webVieRes;
    private DatabaseReference mdataRef;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_page);
        mdataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("weber");
        webviewthis = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        webviewthis.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webviewthis.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewthis.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mdataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             post2web webView = dataSnapshot.getValue(post2web.class);
                webviewthis.loadUrl(webView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**webView xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView_news"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

**getter and setter class file:**

```
public class post2web {
    private String webViewPost;


    public post2web(){
    }

    public post2web(String webViewPost) {
        this.webViewPost = webViewPost;
    }


    public String getWebViewPost() {
        return webViewPost;
    }

    public void setWebViewPost(String webViewPost) {
        this.webViewPost = webViewPost;
    }
}
```

**Firebase rules:**
[image]

**Firebase Database structure for webView**

[image]

Comment: You should do `webviewthis.loadUrl(webView.getWebViewPost());`

Comment: @MarianoCordoba tried this already, but it does not work :(

Comment: Are you allowed to access Firebase database? Check your rules.

Comment: Don't ignore `onCancelled`: `@Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
 throw databaseError.toException();
            }`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what will happen with this   throw databaseError.toException();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. I'm pretty sure that the only problem are the Firebase database rules.

Change your database rules in Firebase and everything will work.

[image]

Comment: i guess my rules are okay, i am going to post it above please check

Comment: With that rules you need to be authenticated to access database. Are you authenticated? If not, use this rules and try again.

Comment: Damn, thats really weird. I'm using your code and everything is working. Can you post your Firebase database structure? (hide sensitive info)

Comment: i am really very sorry it is very difficult to hide, there are lot of things there and cant be hidden completely.Please, can you show me yours as it will be easy and i will tell you that i am implementing the same or not. I hope you understand

Comment: Okay i can show you as much i can and please tell me is it okay and i am going to update it above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153566/discussion-between-marianocordoba-and-rohit-b).

Comment: can you please help me out with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46093182/adding-youtube-api-with-recyclerview-using-firebase-in-android